# Argparser - optional argument before positional argument in a subparser

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, argparse

I want to use my script with an optional argument before a positional one like this:

script.py ls --fruit apple kitchen

- "ls" is a subcommand as below
- "fruit" is the optional one that may or may not be present
- "kitchen" is my positional one that i named "location"

> ```
> parser_ls = subparsers.add_parser('ls', help='Lists all fruits in the location', add_help=False)
> parser_ls.add_argument('--fruit', type=str, dest="fruits", nargs='?')    
> parser_ls.add_argument('location', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
> ```

At the moment i tried using nargs=argparse.REMAINDER for the "location", but i will get all values in the location namespace and None in the fruits and this is not what i want.

```
Namespace(location=['--fruits', 'apple', 'kitchen'], help_down=False, fruits=None)
```

Comment: Hi, if i replace REMAINDER with * it won't see my value of the "location" unless i place it first as "ls kitchen --fruits apple", but i want to get "ls --fruits apple kitchen". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With your code:

```
In [206]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                                
In [207]: sp=p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')                                                            

In [209]: parser_ls = sp.add_parser('ls', help='Lists all fruits in the location', add_help=False) 
     ...: parser_ls.add_argument('--fruit', type=str, dest="fruits", nargs='?');     
     ...: parser_ls.add_argument('location', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER);
```

I get a different namespace.  `fruits` does get the string.  `REMAINDER` only gets one string.

```
In [210]: p.parse_args('ls --fruit apple kitchen'.split())                                           
Out[210]: Namespace(cmd='ls', fruits='apple', location=['kitchen'])
```

Just to check, which python version are you using?

## script

Moving this code to a script:

```
import argparse
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                                
sp=p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')                                                            

parser_ls = sp.add_parser('ls', help='Lists all fruits in the location', add_help=False) 
parser_ls.add_argument('--fruit', type=str, dest="fruits", nargs='?')    
parser_ls.add_argument('location', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

args = p.parse_args()
print(args)
```

test cases:

```
1443:~/mypy$ python3 stack63001317.py 
Namespace(cmd=None)
1139:~/mypy$ python3 stack63001317.py ls
Namespace(cmd='ls', fruits=None, location=[])
1139:~/mypy$ python3 stack63001317.py ls --fruit apple kitchen
Namespace(cmd='ls', fruits='apple', location=['kitchen'])
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.8. How do i use that .split when coding? At the moment my parse looks like args = parser.parse_args(). I get the error "error: unrecognized arguments: location"

Comment: I'm using that `'....'.split()` to generate a test input, instead of taking it from the default `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: So why am i getting a different Namespace then? i reran now and still getting ' python3.8 script.py ls --fruit apple kitchen '
"Namespace(location=['ls', '--fruit', 'apple', 'kitchen'], help_down=False, fruits=None)"

Comment: I also tried just the code that you have above and what i get is "Namespace(fruits=None, location=['ls', '--fruit', 'apple', 'kitchen'])" so it's the same issue. I think you get a different result because of the split. How do i incorporate this into the code above? Thank you!

Comment: Another thing is that if i print the len of the location it will say 1, so i am thinking this is a bug and if i print the args.fruits i get the correct value "apple" instead of None...

Comment: I moved my code to script to show how it works with real command line values.